# How to go back one step in the Share charm with keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, charms-bar

Let's say I'm in the Reader app and I want to share the currently read PDF file. So I:

1. Open the Charms bar
2. Choose the Share charm
3. Choose Mail as the app I want to share with.

Then I realise I made a mistake and want to go back to the list of applications compatible with the Share charm. I know I can press the *left arrow* button with my mouse, but how to do it with a keyboard? In some places, it's possible to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, but here it just doesn't work. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> hides the whole charm bar and I have to start from the beginning. Is there a shortcut I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Share charm.  This will take you back a step just like you wanted in your example.

A list of keyboard shortcuts can be found here: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hyperyash/list-of-windows-8-shortcuts)